# Помогите сократить файл. Нужно минифицировать(сократить) код в файле

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
  let filter = $("[data-filter]");

  filter.on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let cat = $(this).data("filter");

    if (cat == "all") {
      $("[data-cat]").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
      $("[data-cat]").each(function () {
        let workCat = $(this).data("cat");

        if (workCat != cat) {
          $(this).addClass("hide");
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("hide");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

$(".cards__menu_tab li a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".cards__menu_tab li a").removeClass("cards__menu_list_active");
  $(this).addClass("cards__menu_list_active");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("ul.bar-section__menu_top").on(
    "click",
    "li:not(.bar-section__menu_items active)",
    function () {
      $(this)
        .addClass("active")
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("active")
        .closest("div.bar-section__menu_top")
        .find("div.bar-section__menu_items")
        .removeClass("active")
        .eq($(this).index())
        .addClass("active");
    }
  );
});

var target = ".cards__items";

jQuery(target).each(function () {
  jQuery(this).click(function () {
    location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
  });
  jQuery(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
});

$(".cards__popular ul li a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".cards__popular ul li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$(".cards__items").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".cards__items").removeClass("cards__items_pinned");
  $(this).addClass("cards__items_pinned");
});

var target = "#socialtab";

jQuery(target).each(function () {
  jQuery(this).click(function () {
    location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
  });
  jQuery(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
});

var animateButton = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  //reset animation
  e.target.classList.remove("animate");

  e.target.classList.add("animate");
  setTimeout(function () {
    e.target.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 700);
};

var bubblyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("bubbly-button");

for (var i = 0; i < bubblyButtons.length; i++) {
  bubblyButtons[i].addEventListener("click", animateButton, false);
}

var animateButton = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  //reset animation
  e.target.classList.remove("animate");

  e.target.classList.add("animate");
  setTimeout(function () {
    e.target.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 700);
};

var bubblyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("bubbly-blue");

for (var i = 0; i < bubblyButtons.length; i++) {
  bubblyButtons[i].addEventListener("click", animateButton, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp/webpack/grunt в помощь

ну или найти какой нибудь онлайн инструмент

как пример есть вот такой ресурс https://javascript-minifier.com